# I want to view selected data from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to view each row using PHP and MySQL but earlier I used XHR for a live update this data from the database. I'm guessing I'll need to use Jquery but I lack the knowledge on how to do so.

```
            var html ="";

for (var a=0;a<data.length;a++)
{   
    var devid =data[a].dev_ID;
    var devname =data[a].dev_Name;
    var devstatus  =data[a].dev_Status;
    var reading01 = data[a].dev_Reading01;
    var reading02 = data[a].dev_Reading02;

    //html += "<tr>";
       // html += "<td>"+firstName+"</td>";
        //html += "<td>"+lastName+"</td>";
        //html += "<td>"+jobTitle+"</td>";
        //html += "<td>"+devstatus+"</td>";
        //html += "</tr>";
    html +='<div class="row mt-2 mb-2 bg-info height" >';
    html += '<div class="container-fluid ex3" >';
        html +='<div  class="row mt-2 mb-2 bg-info height" >';
        html += '<div class="col-4">Name:<br>'+devname+'</a></div>';
        html += '<div class="col-2">Status<br>'+devstatus+'</div>';
        html += '<div class="col-2">Reading 01<br>'+reading01+'</div>';
        html += '<div class="col-2">Reading 02<br>'+reading02+'</div>';
        html += '<div class="col-2">Status<br>'+devstatus+'</div>';
        html += "</div>";
        html += "</div>";
        html += "</div>";
       // html += "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = html;

              }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the jquery data table plugin wherein you can pass your "data"

https://datatables.net/

```
    $('#id').dataTable( {
  "aaData": data,
  "aoColumns": [
    { "sTitle": "title1" },
    { "sTitle": "title2" },
    { "sTitle": "title3" },
    { "sTitle": "title4"}
  ]
});
```